# Delete files older than given time from directory

Tags: android, file-io

I have created list of files to store some attribute after they are opened once in my app.
Every time the file is opened those attributes are changed so I made them be deleted and created again.

I have created all the files files using

```
File file =new File(getExternalFilesDir(null),
                currentFileId+"");
if(file.exists()){
           //I store the required attributes here and delete them
           file.delete();
}else{
          file.createNewFile();
}
```

I want to delete all of those files here older than a week as those stored attributes won't be required any more.
What'd be the appropriate method to do so?

Comment: Creating files to temporarily store attributes sounds like a bad idea, if your attributes are number or strings.
Storing the data in an SQL database is likely much more efficient and practical.

Comment: those files are of very small size
I wonder if those no of files get high in number and fill the memory of device with relatively low memory space, it'd create a problem.
for that purpose only I want to delete those files.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This should do the trick. It will create a calendar instance to 7 days ago and compare if the modified date of the file is before that time. If it is that means that the file is older than 7 days.

```
    if(file.exists()){
        Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
        time.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,-7);
        //I store the required attributes here and delete them
        Date lastModified = new Date(file.lastModified());
        if(lastModified.before(time.getTime())) {
            //file is older than a week
            file.delete();
        }
    }else{
        file.createNewFile();
    }
```

If you want to get all the files in a dir you can use this and then iterate the result and compare each file.

```
public static ArrayList<File> getAllFilesInDir(File dir) {
    if (dir == null)
        return null;

    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();

    Stack<File> dirlist = new Stack<File>();
    dirlist.clear();
    dirlist.push(dir);

    while (!dirlist.isEmpty()) {
        File dirCurrent = dirlist.pop();

        File[] fileList = dirCurrent.listFiles();
        for (File aFileList : fileList) {
            if (aFileList.isDirectory())
                dirlist.push(aFileList);
            else
                files.add(aFileList);
        }
    }

    return files;
}
```

Comment: File file =new File(getExternalFilesDir(null),
                currentFileId+"");


It creates filenamed with the id.I want to delete file without knowing what the file name is as I won't be remembering all those id of every file

Comment: Then you can iterate all the files in the dir and check if they are older than 7 days.

Comment: I got problem here in iterating, without knowing the file name I want to delete them

Comment: You don't have to know the file's name since they are store in an array of Files...Why do you want the name?

Comment: Thanks I got my solution combining with @Sagar Pilkhwal

Answer (score 3):

```
if (file.exists()) {
  Date today = new Date();

  int diffInDays = (int)( (today.getTime() - file.lastModified()) /(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) );
  if(diffInDays>7){
            System.out.println("File is one week old");
            //you can delete the file here
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to transform the file's modified long to a date since you're using the milliseconds anyway. But overall a good approach too.

Comment: thanks I got my solution :) combining your code with of @PedroOliveira

Comment: is it a week old or a day? :P

Comment: `if(diffInDays>7)` its a week old, great that you found your answer, vote-up if possible

Answer (score 0):

File.lastModified() returns a long Int in [Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)